# Is there any way to find user is interacting with Mouse or Finger in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, touch, multi-touch

I want to detect whether user is interacting with Mouse or Finger in my WPF application based on that I want to change my UI(Changing the Context Menu style-more easy interact in touch).

Is there any class available in C# or any native methods are available to find that?

Answer (score 0):

We have a couple of events like `TouchDown`, `TouchUp`, `TouchEnter`, `TouchMove` which will notify on each action user performs. Please visit below links for more.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/12/07/wpf-touch-basics.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff898416.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Check the value of e.StylusDevice (MouseEventArgs). If null then it is mouse else you will get the instance of touch device. Hope it helps..

Comment: StylusDevice are only available in WinRT.Can u pls confirm with WPF?

Comment: Can you check once again? I posted after verifying with a WPF sample. Also thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fb091b9-bdb6-4173-b709-538d8abddda9/stylusdeviceposition-vs-using-styluspoints-wpf proves WPF has e.StylusDevice.